# What is the name of this plant that has flowers resembling white filaments?

Tags: identification, flowers, wildflowers

I came across this flower in Maharashtra, India. I don't have much information about it.

[image]

Comment: It looks like a snakeroot - genus Ageratina . I don't know if it is found in India. http://swbiodiversity.org/seinet/taxa/index.php?taxon=207322